# Trace of a weighted composition operator on Bergman space

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

I am reading a series of papers by Pollicott, Jenkinson and coauthors which make use of the following type of result:

**Theorem:** Let $\mathbb{D} \subset \mathbb{C}^d$ be a bounded, connected open set. Let $\varphi \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ be holomorphic and suppose that $\varphi(\mathbb{D})$ is a precompact subset of $\mathbb{D}$.  Then $\varphi$ has a unique fixed point $z_0 \in \mathbb{D}$, and $D_{z_0}\varphi$ has spectral radius strictly less than $1$. Let $g \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and bounded and define an operator $\mathcal{L} \colon A^2(\mathbb{D}) \to A^2(\mathbb{D})$ by $(\mathcal{L}f)(z):=g(z)f(\varphi(z))$. Then  $\mathcal{L}$ is well-defined and trace-class with trace equal to $g(z_0)/(\det(I-D_{z_0}\varphi))$.

The choice of Bergman space $A^2(\mathbb{D})$ is somewhat arbitrary and I would imagine that a wide range of holomorphic function spaces can be used instead.

Some of the articles I am looking at use only the case $d=1$, but others use the general case. I have found the references provided for this result a little vague: [3] below says "by Fredholm theory" and cites *Produits tensoriels topologiques et espaces nucléaires* by Grothendieck without a page reference. (I cannot find the result in the cited paper.) It also cites Ruelle, who in turn states that the trace can be computed "by standard Fredholm theory" and cites a different paper by Grothendieck, *La théorie de Fredholm*, also without a page reference. The same pattern is followed in [4], which also cites *The zeta functions of Ruelle and Selberg* by David Fried. That paper contains some somewhat similar-looking calculations, but (it seems to me) not quite the ones required.

The papers [1,2] use only the case d=1, and [1] is more explicit: it cites *Continued fractions and related transformations* by Dieter Mayer which proves the case $d=1$ in detail (as Corollary 7.1) and states the higher-dimensional case as a remark without proof. I have not been able to find the case $d>1$ written down explicitly anywhere and have not yet been able to produce a complete proof myself. The essence of the trace calculation seems to be to show that the nonzero eigenvalues of $\mathcal{L}$ are precisely products of the form $g(z_0)\lambda_1^{n_1}\cdots \lambda_d^{n_d}$ where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d$ is the complete list of eigenvalues of $D_{z_0}\varphi$ and the integers $n_1,\ldots,n_d$ range over all non-negative integer values.

Since this result seems to be used quite widely, I feel like a detailed proof ought to exist in the literature somewhere. Is anyone able to direct me to a reference?

[1] Oliver Jenkinson and Mark Pollicott, Computing the dimension of dynamically defined sets: E2 and bounded continued fractions. Ergodic Theory & Dynamical Systems 2001.

[2] Oliver Jenkinson and Mark Pollicott, Calculating Hausdorff dimensions of Julia sets and Kleinian limit sets, American Journal of Mathematics 2002.

[3] Mark Pollicott and Oliver Jenkinson, Computing Invariant Densities and Metric Entropy, Communications in Mathematical Physics 2000.

[4] Mark Pollicott, Maximal Lyapunov exponents for random matrix products, Inventions Mathematicae 2010.